# É possível pegar dentro de uma array um dado especifico de um objeto?

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Sou novo na programação, estou com uma dúvida em relação a pegar um dado especifico que esta dentro do Array
Atualmente o código se encontra assim:

```
ArrayList<Campos> todosCampos;

for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                botao = new Campos(i, true, false);
                todosCampos.add(botao);
            }
```

Os Campos são Jbuttons e tem id, boolean1, boolean2;

no caso eu gostaria de saber se consigo ir na lista por exemplo e fazer um

```
todosCampos.get(1).getId();
```

No caso retornaria apenas o id de Campos, por exemplo:

```
1;
```

já tentei de algumas formas mas não consegui, apenas consigo fazer retornar o Campo completo dessa forma:

```
Campos [id=1, minado=false, status=false]
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?(estou aprendendo sozinho e algumas coisas ainda não consegue associar)

Comment: Veja em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376735/how-to-return-a-specific-element-of-an-array

Comment: obg por ter respondido, dei uma olhada no link, porem, só que ainda não é o que eu gostaria exatamente
vamos supor, tenho uma classe Botao (int id, boolean bomba)
entao eu crio uma ArrayList<Botao> todosBotoes;
a dentro coloco diversos botoes com diferentes ids por exemplo
todosBotoes.add(new Botao(1, true);
todosBotoes.add(new Botao(2, true);
e assim por diante
entao eu gostaria de selecionar na lista o botao por exemplo que esta no index 4
e desse botao extrair apenas o id
ja tentei fazer um getId() na classe Botao, mas sempre me retorna o ultimo Id pq criei os botoes usando FOR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Também sou iniciante em Java e não sei se entendi direito a dúvida.

Mas se ID é uma variável de instância da sua classe botão, você tem duas formas de acessar ela, declarando ela como `public` dentro da classe, ai você faria algo do tipo:

```
todosCampos.get(1).Id;
```

Se a variável é do tipo `private`, você pode criar um método dentro da sua classe que retorna a variável e que seja acessível fora da classe:

```
public String getId(){
    return Id;
}
```

Então, o código ficaria:

```
todosCampos.get(1).getID();
```

Comment: Cara obrigado, quando eu digitei la em cima o modo que eu gostaria de fazer como exemplo, eu não achei que realmente poderia ser feito daquele jeito, achei que o getId() só funcionaria se fosse se referindo a uma Classe onde o metodo dele estava, vlwww!! agora parece boba a pergunta, mas eu tava preso nisso uns dias